# Symfony2 and Translatable I can not get the translations in some entities

Tags: symfony

I have a problem with Symfony2 and DoctrineBehaviors Translatable. I already have all the entities translated, buy in some cases, I have a problem getting the translations.
For example, I have a category entity and when I try this code, it does not work properly.

```
        if($category->getId() == 61) {
        echo "ES => ".$category->translate('es')->getName()."<br>"; //ES => PROMOCIONALES<br>
        echo "EN => ".$category->translate('en')->getName()."<br>"; //EN => <br>
        echo "FR => ".$category->translate('fr')->getName()."<br>"; //FR => <br>
    }
```

But the category with id 61, has the next entries on the translations table
[image]

So I don know how can I fix it. Anybody knows where can be the problem?

Thank you and regards!

UPDATE: I couldn't solve this 3 months later, any help?
UPDATE 2: There is a new test, printing the translations of a post entity (I just discover that also happens in other entities).

```
public function debugAction()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $post = $em->getRepository('NewsBundle:Post')->findOneById(31);

    \Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($post->getTranslations()->toArray());

    return $this->render('CoreBundle:Test:test.html.twig', array(
    ));
}
```

[image]

[image]

If you need any more info, please, tell me! Thank you in advance!

UPDATE 3: I just discovered that if I call a repository function that filters by locale, the result is cached and the post call is not executed in doctrine. How can I prevent that? In some cases (like articles/news) I need to get only the entities that have been translated in a specific locale... Buy if I filter by locale, I can not get all translations later...

UPDATE 4: Using $em->clear(); seems that is working correctly. I think that is the best option... I'm going to call this method into all backend controllers.

Comment: I still have this problem, any solution? :(

Comment: What's your default locale? Do you have all corresponding records in category_translation table?

Comment: My default locale is 'en'. Yes, 'en' is in the table. Thanks.

Comment: Could u make a dump of $category->translations collection? And also the list of performing queries to database?

Comment: Hi @DmitryMalyshenko I gonna edit with your request. Thank you!

Comment: You've posted dump for a different entity so it's not clear what is wrong behaviour. 

So this $post is not working properly too? What fields and in which locales don't work?

Comment: Just to try to help you out, did you create a YourEntityTranslation entity as documentation shows? Did you add the ORMBehaviors\Translatable\Translatable; trait to your original entity? Do you execute $yourEntity->mergeNewTranslations(); before flush to save translations properly? Did you move (not copied) your translatable fields from the original entity to the translations entity?

Comment: I've edited with new info. I discover that if I call a repository function that filter some news by entity and later I call the findBy function, this do not return all translations, only the previous filtered translations...

Comment: @David Is there a public repository that we could check. I've worked with this bundle many times without a problem. If I can take a look at the code on a repository I will definitly be able to help you.

Comment: @MichaelVilleneuve We don't have any public repository, but I find a solution (for now) clearing the entity manager cache. I'm trying and know works. The problem was that in the frontend, in some entities like news or events, I only want entities with an specific translations and I use a where clause like "t.locale = 'en'". I think that is all ok now but I'm still checking that. I'll inform if I find any problem! Thank you!